# Excel : I have an offset from requested position

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to insert pictures at différent position. It is managed by a loop that will space each pictures by 23 columns.

```vba
'insert le graph
     chemin = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\graph1.jpg"
     cht.Chart.Export Filename:=chemin, filtername:="JPG" ' enregistre le graphique en .jpg
     ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Rapport").Pictures.Insert (chemin)
     Dim myShape As Shape
     Set myShape = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Rapport").Shapes(ligne)
 
     With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Rapport")
           myShape.Top = .Range("A" & 23 * (ligne - 1) + 10).Top
           myShape.Left = .Range("A" & 23 * (ligne - 1) + 10).Left
           myShape.Width = .Range("A1:R1").Width
           myShape.Height = .Range("A" & 23 * (ligne - 1) + 10 & ":" & "A" & 23 * (ligne) + 7).Height
           myShape.IncrementRotation 360 'or 90
     End With
```

With this code i obtain for the first picture:
[image]

And 23 row below we can see a shift:
[image]

I don't understand why the Top function of Range don't give the good position.

Thank you in advance for your help !

**Edit**

I try with the idea of Tim William and now I have a downward shift.
[image]

Comment: Try setting the top/left after you've done the resizing.  Also check the "postion" settings (whether the images moves with cells or moves and sizes for example) and make sure the "lock aspect ratio" property is false before resizing.

Comment: I try with your idea and now there is a downward shift xD